# What optical element can you use to implement a square root of NOT gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

How do you implement a **square root of NOT gate** in an optical quantum computing circuit? What optical element or combination of elements would you use - especially, if you want to manipulate polarization qubits?

The *square root of not gate* has the following matrix representation:
$$ \sqrt{X} = \sqrt{NOT} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1+i & 1-i \\ 1-i & 1+i \end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: It would perhaps be best if you posted this on quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com. Our quantum computing SE site. thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited to quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for physics than quantum computing stack exchange because the answer  will involve theoretical and experimental aspects of optics. It does not matter for the answer the application for the question is quantum computing.

Comment: @josephh Quantum Computing questions are completely on topic here. Not to mention the quantum optics part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a polarization qubit, you need to rotate the polarization. This is done with a [waveplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate). A $\lambda/2$ plate implements a NOT gate. Thus, a $\lambda/4$ plate will implement a square root of the NOT gate.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm whether my understanding is correct, that would be a quarter-wave plate with a 45-degree angle between the fast axis and whatever polarization corresponds to the input (e.g., |0> encoded in horizontal polarization)?